# regex issue with chemical formula. can't get rid of '' for the number and return tuple

Tags: python-3.x

```
import re

def molecule_to_list(molecule):
    return re.findall(r'([A-Z][a-z]*)(\d*)',molecule)

print(molecule_to_list('CaO3H'))
```

This is my output ('Ca', ''), ('O', '3'), ('H', '')

But I want ('Ca', 1 ), ('O', 3), ('H', 1)

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow.](https://stackoverflow.com/ "Stack Overflow")! It is very difficult to answer your question without seeing any of your input data. Please read about how to ask a good question and try to post a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example "Minimal Reproducible Example") so we can better help you.

Answer (score 1):

The result is a list of tuples. You want to iterate through them and replace the string with integer. If the string is empty, replace with 1.

```
import re

def molecule_to_list(molecule):
    return [(x,int(y)) if y != '' else (x,1) for x,y in re.findall(r'([A-Z][a-z]*)(\d*)',molecule)  ]

print(molecule_to_list('CaO3H'))
```

Output will be:

```
[('Ca', 1), ('O', 3), ('H', 1)]
```